# pig latin force unique contraint

Tags: apache-pig

I need some help how to reach in pig that for a certain field only one record is taken.

```
A = load .... ;
```

/*
data looks like:

transaction_id,   prod_id,  date

1,     123,   20140102

1,     124,   20140102

1,     125,   20140102

2,     233,   20140107

2,     245,   20140107

3,     255,   20140109
*/

```
B = GROUP A BY transaction_id;

C = FOREACH B {
limited = LIMIT A 1;
GENERATE FLATTEN(limited);
};
```

i expect that it gives back 3 records, but only gives 1 record.

what i am doing wrong?

thanks for reply in advance.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the actual output you get?

Comment: thanks for the reply i have found the problem. shame on me but i forget to change the field separator at load and thats why it only gave back one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the problem. shame on me but i forget to change the field separator at load and thats why it only gave back one record